# Nerdtree not recognized as command in VIM (ubuntu)

Tags: vim, nerdtree, pathogen

I have installed pathogen.vim from github into the `.vim/autoload` directory and have edited my .vimrc to include the following lines

```
pathogen#infect()
pathogen#helptags()

autocmd vimenter * NERDtree
```

I have installed the latest version of nerdtree from [GitHub > scrooloose/nerdtree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) into my `.vim/bundle` directory

despite this, vim tells me that NERDtree is not a recognized command. I am now at a loss. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Steve Kane

Comment: If in doubt, you can do `:NERD<Tab>` to see all the NERDTree-related commands available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NERDtree => NERDTree (capital T)